# Dynamically Change Three.js texture in externally loaded Collada file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the three.js collada loader to import an .dae file with a texture (.png) image applied. I need to overwrite the .png file with a new texture, and am creating this texture using a canvas element that exports to .png format. If I clear my cache, it will change the texture (I am naming the exported "new" .png texture as the same filename as the original .png texture referenced in the .dae file).

How can I ensure that the new texture is recognized/rendered without having the user clear their cache? Example: User creates a new texture, and it is exported over the original texture, and the collada file re-renders after a user clicks a button to render the box.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a Javascript Image object in memory, regardless of the source, you can assign it to your objects' materials' textures via the `.image` attribute. You'll need to let THRE.js know to alter the binding. For example, if you have a new Image called, say, `img` and a mesh called `mesh` with a typical material:

```
mesh.material.map.image = img;
mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

should do the trick. No need to send a DOM elemetn to disk as a .png, just use it.

Comment: The image source is bound in the Collada files XML. Will mesh still update in this case? Currently it is stating "mesh is not defined". Is the a way to define the mesh to the texture defined in the collada file?

Comment: after you call the collada loader load(), everything lives in the JS-based scene graph's `.scene` element. Depending on the hierarchy of your object(s) you'll just have to track down the bits you need, and then manipulate like any other mesh.

f you get a bit trickier, you can look at the `.images` references and try to intercept the names there before they get loaded. But it sounds more like you want to be changing things in an ongoing way, rather than interrupting the scene load, yes?

Comment: That is correct, and very helpful. I want to be able to re-wrap textures on click